# How to highlight certain months in year view with certain color in kendo datepicker?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

The task that I want to solve is based on certain conditions.

I want to highlight certain months of year in year view of kendo datepicker.

For highlighting specific dates in kendo datepicker, I have used "month" attribute and templating.

But for months I am not getting way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of passing a template for years, decades only valid options is months.

Also the views for months, years, etc. are rendered in the same table and there are no extra css class attached to a certain view to help you overrride them.

The only option which is not a relialble one is to search using jquery selectors in .k-calendar-container class for the first table and then when you find the month text replace it's html content with what you want.

Comment: One more thing... just wanna know if i do as u have said... i am bit doubtful that once applied style to a particular month tag, will be retained once the user changes the year ......

Comment: Yes you were right i investigated a little bit and there seems to be no way of doing that. Also the month names are changing if you will use a different culture.